# Different 'template path' per view?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I want to get:

```
/mytheme-directory
  /front-slides
    /views-view--front-slides--block.tpl.php
    /views-view-unformatted--front-slides--block.tpl.php
    /views-view-fields--front-slides--block.tpl.php
  /front-4-cats
    /views-view--front-4-cats--block.tpl.php
    /views-view-unformatted--front-4-cats--block.tpl.php
    /views-view-fields--front-4-cats--block.tpl.php
```

instead:

```
/mytheme-directory
  /views-view--front-slides--block.tpl.php
  /views-view-unformatted--front-slides--block.tpl.php
  /views-view-fields--front-slides--block.tpl.php
  /views-view--front-4-cats--block.tpl.php
  /views-view-unformatted--front-4-cats--block.tpl.php
  /views-view-fields--front-4-cats--block.tpl.php
```

Can I use different 'template path' or do something else? easy way please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are instructions for doing this on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/430980).

Also, here's a [general article on organizing your theme files in Drupal](http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/17-organizing-your-theme-files-drupal).